# Arduino with servos, tone() function and RGB led

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, led, pwm, servo

I'm doing an Arduino Project with 2 servos, 1 buzzer, and 1 RGB LED.

I have an Arduino Uno Board, with 6 PWM pins (3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11).

The problem is that I need 3 pins with PWM for the RGB LED, but the servo library disables PWM on pins 9 and 10.

From https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/servo/:

> On boards other than the Mega, use of the library disables analogWrite() (PWM) functionality on pins 9 and 10, whether or not there is a Servo on those pins.

And the `tone()` function to use the buzzer interferes with thd  PWM output on pins 3 and 11. From https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/:

> Use of the tone() function will interfere with PWM output on pins 3 and 11 (on boards other than the Mega).

So, there are only pins 5 and 6 fkr my RGB LED.

Is there some way to use Servo without the library? Or to control the buzzer without the `tone()` function?

Comment: use an active buzzer. that will buzz with simple digitalWrite

Comment: Active buzzer is one way.  Another is to realize you don't need the crappy and bloated library to control a stepper.  All you need is one pin per stepper.  My hexapod robots from years ago used 18 servos on a single 16-bit timer.

Answer (score 1):

What Juraj said. Also:

There are libraries for software PWM you could use, see [SoftPWM](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/SoftPWM) and (an edited fork of the first one) [SoftPWM](https://github.com/bhagman/SoftPWM).

They use only one timer, and can produce PWM signals on any pin.

I haven't tried and tested those libraries myself, but I assume they work well.

If you ever go the SAMD21 way, there's a PWM library for those Arduinos that use that microcontroller [here](https://github.com/ocrdu/Arduino_SAMD21_turbo_PWM). Had to say that, because I wrote it. Sorry.